# What does the real axis of a transfer function mean?

Tags: transfer-function, lti-system

Let's say I have a system that has a transfer function \$ H(s) \$. Now \$ s = \sigma + j \omega \$, so \$ H(s) = H(\sigma + j \omega) \$. If I am not mistaken, the imaginary axis \$ j \omega \$ describes the oscillation frequency of an input, and \$ H( j \omega) \$ describes how the system responds to that frequency. What I don't understand is what the real axis \$ \sigma \$ describes, nor why is it in units of Hertz.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EE.SE.

As you noted, the imaginary axis shows the frequency of oscillation of a system.

The real axis shows how the amplitude of that oscillation varies with time. For σ = 0 (i.e. all along the imaginary jw axis) the amplitude is constant.

For negative σ the amplitude will decay exponentially. As the system response moves further away to the left from the imaginary axis (becoming more negative) the faster it will decay.

For positive σ the amplitude will grow exponentially. As the system response moves further away to the right from the imaginary axis (becoming more positive) the faster it will grow.

A system that is operating in the right-half of the s plane, with positive σ,  will have a response that keeps growing (until it hits the physical limits of the system). It is said to be unstable.

In control system theory considerable effort goes into determining if a system is stable, and making it stable if it is found to be unstable.

> why is σ in units of Hertz?

Hertz have units of per second. σ is a time constant, telling us how much the amplitude of the system response grows or shrinks per second so units of Hz are still dimensionally appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that we have the differential equation in the time domain for a frequency-dependent circuit. For solving this diff.equation (finding the "characteristic equation") we are using an ansatz Ke^st - without knowing the meaning of the factor "s".

However, within this process we come to the conclusion that "s" has the unit 1/time and very often consists of a real as well as imag. part (Example: RLC circuits).

This leads to the well-known expression "s=σ+jω".

When we introduce this complexe frequency term into the exponential function e^st and after applying Euler´s formula we find that the solution in the time domain has the form:

**K(e^σt)*(sin(ωt)).**

For a passive system, the factor σ will be always negative and the solution, therefore, is a damped sinusoidal signal.

This is the background for introducing the concept of "complexe frequencies". For some graphical analyses (pole location, root locus, Nyquist curve) we use the so-called s-plane with the **damping coefficient "σ" on the real axis and "jω" on the vertical imag. axis.**

This allows us to analyze magnitude and phase of a complexe function in one single diagram. Such a diagram contains the same information as the Bode diagram, which however, consists of two separate diagrams (magnitude and phase).

I hope this answers your question.